# htaccess 301 redirect domain but not a specific folder and files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I tried searching in first here in stackoverflow and google for the best answer but I could not find a solution to my problem.

My question is can I add a condition where a specific sets of folder/files in my server will not be affected by a htaccess 301 redirection from old domain to new domain?

this is the htaccess I added.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mysite.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

the old domain was mysite.com without the .au and the above code will direct all links in my old site to be transfer to .com.au , but I want some of my folder in .com to be not affected by the htaccess 301 redirection, for example.

```
mysite.com/folder1/,
mysite.com/images/, 
mysite.com/js/
```

and some files will not be affected by this redirection. Can any one point me to on how to fix or add a rule so a specific folder will not be affected by the old domain to new domain htaccess 301 redirection I added?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `RewriteCond` in your redirect rule for exceptions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(folder/|images/|js/) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```